# PyTorch: How to use DataLoaders for custom Datasets

Tags: python, torch, pytorch

How to make use of the `torch.utils.data.Dataset` and `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` on your own data (not just the `torchvision.datasets`)?

Is there a way to use the inbuilt `DataLoaders` which they use on `TorchVisionDatasets` to be used on any dataset?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. Just create the objects by yourself, e.g.

```
import torch.utils.data as data_utils

train = data_utils.TensorDataset(features, targets)
train_loader = data_utils.DataLoader(train, batch_size=50, shuffle=True)
```

where `features` and `targets` are tensors. `features` has to be 2-D, i.e. a matrix where each line represents one training sample, and `targets` may be 1-D or 2-D, depending on whether you are trying to predict a scalar or a vector.

---

**EDIT**: response to @sarthak's question

Basically yes. If you create an object of type `TensorData`, then the constructor investigates whether the first dimensions of the feature tensor (which is actually called `data_tensor`) and the target tensor (called `target_tensor`) have the same length:

```
assert data_tensor.size(0) == target_tensor.size(0)
```

However, if you want to feed these data into a neural network subsequently, then you need to be careful. While convolution layers work on data like yours, (I think) all of the other types of layers expect the data to be given in matrix form. So, if you run into an issue like this, then an easy solution would be to convert your 4D-dataset (given as some kind of tensor, e.g. `FloatTensor`) into a matrix by using the method `view`. For your 5000xnxnx3 dataset, this would look like this:

```
2d_dataset = 4d_dataset.view(5000, -1)
```

(The value `-1` tells PyTorch to figure out the length of the second dimension automatically.)

Comment: I have 3D features : 2D for an image and one extra dimension for color channels. Would it still work if I pass the features as 5000xnxnx3. 5000 is the number of data points nxnx3 is the image size

Comment: A 4d Dataset can be passed as features there is no need for the view statement.

Comment: @pho7 You say the `features` matrix is 2D and contains lines of input data. This makes sense to me if the input data is 1D (such as a voice signal or so..), but what if it is an image (2D) say 32x32? How would the `features` matrix look like?

Comment: It's probably flattened, and you would need to reshape it when you load it from the DataLoader? I'm not sure though

Answer (score 13):

You can easily do this be extending the `data.Dataset` class.
According to the [API](http://pytorch.org/docs/torchvision/datasets.html), all you have to do is implement two function: `__getitem__` and `__len__`.

You can then wrap the dataset with the DataLoader as shown in the API and in @pho7 's answer.

I think the `ImageFolder` class is a reference. See code [here](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/master/torchvision/datasets/folder.py).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do it.
Hope this helps for future readers.

```
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader
import torch.utils.data as data_utils

inputs = [[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],[ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6]]
targets = [ 6,7]
batch_size = 2

inputs  = torch.tensor(inputs)
targets = torch.IntTensor(targets)
    
dataset = TensorDataset(inputs, targets)
data_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size, shuffle=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [user3693922's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42202068/8044858) and the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42054194/8044858), which respectively [link](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torchvision/datasets.html) the "quick" PyTorch documentation example to create custom dataloaders for custom datasets, and create a custom dataloader in the "simplest" case, **there is a much more detailed dedicated official PyTorch tutorial** on how to create a custom dataloader with the associated preprocessing: ["writing custom datasets, dataloaders and transforms" official PyTorch tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Pytorch's `DataLoader` is designed to take a `Dataset` object as input, but all it requires is an object with a `__getitem__` and `__len__` attribute, so any generic container will suffice.

E.g. a list of tuples with your features (x values) as the first element, and targets (y values) as the second element can be passed directly to `DataLoader` like so:

```py
x = [6,3,8,2,5,9,7]
y = [1,0,1,0,0,1,1]

data = [*zip(x,y)]
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(data)

for features, targets in dataloader:
    #...
```