# CUDA out of memory when fine-tuning a large model

Tags: pytorch, gpu, transfer-learning

I have previously trained a VGG mode(say model1), and a two layer model(say model2) separately, now I have to train a new model which combines those two models together, and each part of the new model is initialized with the learned weights of model1 and model2, which I implemented as follows:

```
class TransferModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, VGG, TwoLayer):
        super(TransferModel, self).__init__()
        self.vgg_layer=VGG
        self.linear = TwoLayer
        for param in self.vgg_layer.parameters():
            param.requires_grad = True
    def forward(self, x):
        h1_vgg = self.vgg_layer(x)
        y_pred = self.linear(h1_vgg)
        return y_pred
# for image_id in train_ids[0:1]:
#     img = load_image(train_id_to_file[image_id])
new_model=TransferModel(trained_vgg_instance, trained_twolayer_instance)
new_model.linear.load_state_dict(trained_twolayer_instance.state_dict())
new_model.vgg_layer.load_state_dict(trained_vgg_instance.state_dict())
new_model.cuda()
```

And when training, I try:

```
def train(model, learning_rate=0.001, batch_size=50, epochs=2):
    optimizer=optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
    criterion = torch.nn.MultiLabelSoftMarginLoss()
    x = torch.zeros([batch_size, 3, img_size, img_size])
    y_true = torch.zeros([batch_size, 4096])
    for epoch in range(epochs):  # loop over the dataset multiple times
        running_loss = 0.0
        shuffled_indcs=torch.randperm(20000)
        for i in range(20000):
        for batch_num in range(int(20000/batch_size)):
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            for j in range(batch_size):
                # ... some code to load batches of images into x....
            x_batch=Variable(x).cuda()
            print(batch_num)
            y_true_batch=Variable(train_labels[batch_num*batch_size:(batch_num+1)*batch_size, :]).cuda()
            y_pred =model(x_batch)
            loss = criterion(y_pred, y_true_batch)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            running_loss += loss
            del x_batch, y_true_batch, y_pred
            torch.cuda.empty_cache()
        print("in epoch[%d] = %.8f " % (epoch, running_loss /(batch_num+1)))
        running_loss = 0.0

    print('Finished Training')
train(new_model)
```

In the second iteration(batch_num=1) of the first epoch, I get this error:

> CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 153.12 MiB (GPU 0; 5.93 GiB
>   total capacity; 4.83 GiB already allocated; 66.94 MiB free; 374.12 MiB
>   cached)

Although I have explicitly used 'del' in my training, by running nvidia-smi it looks like it doesn't do anything and the memory isn't being freed.

What should I do?

Comment: What is your GPU configuration (count & memory etc)? AFAIK, VGG is memory intensive. Also, have you tried with batch size 1? It reduces memory requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

`running_loss += loss`

to this:

`running_loss += loss.item()`

By adding `loss` to `running_loss`, you are telling pytorch to keep all the gradients with respect to `loss` for that batch in memory, even when you start training on the next batch. Pytorch thinks that maybe you will want to use `running_loss` in some big loss function over multiple batches later, and therefore keeps all the gradients (and therefore activations) for all batches in memory.

By adding `.item()` you just get the loss as a python `float`, rather than a `torch.FloatTensor`. This float is detached from the pytorch graph and thus pytorch knows you don't want gradients with respect to it.

If you are running an older version of pytorch without `.item()`, you can try:

`running_loss += float(loss).cpu().detach`

This could also be caused by a similar bug in a `test()` loop, if you have one.

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't work out after this line

Comment: Interesting. Maybe upgrade pytorch and remove all the Variable( stuff? That's not needed these days

Comment: Also pre-assigning your batch like you do here:

`x = torch.zeros([batch_size, 3, img_size, img_size])`

`y_true = torch.zeros([batch_size, 4096])`

Could be problematic - try assigning it when you create your batch (or even better, use [DataLoaders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41924453/pytorch-how-to-use-dataloaders-for-custom-datasets)).