# PyTorch - How to Save Custom Dataset to disk to use with torchvision.datasets?

Tags: dataset, pytorch, torchvision

I'd like to create a custom PyTorch dataset of ZCA-whitened CIFAR-10 that I can subsequently load using torchvision's function `torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10()`. So far, I can successfully whiten the data (see code below), but I don't know how to save the data to disk in a manner that allows it to be loaded using `torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10()`. How do I do this?

Code to ZCA-whiten CIFAR 10:

```
    trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(
        root='./datasets',
        train=True,
        download=False)
    train_data = trainset.data.reshape(-1, 32*32*3)
    zca_matrix = zca_whitening_matrix(train_data.T)
    whitened_training_data = np.matmul(zca_matrix, train_data.T).T
    whitened_training_data = whitened_training_data.reshape((-1, 32, 32, 3))

    # whiten CIFAR-10 testing data
    testset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(
        root='./datasets',
        train=False,
        download=False)
    testdata = testset.data.reshape(-1, 32*32*3)
    whitened_test_data = np.matmul(zca_matrix, testdata.T).T
    whitened_test_data = whitened_test_data.reshape((-1, 32, 32, 3))
```

Is the best way to really just save the numpy arrays, as shown here?

[PyTorch: How to use DataLoaders for custom Datasets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41924453/pytorch-how-to-use-dataloaders-for-custom-datasets?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible by default for any of the [datasets](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/datasets.html).

The recommended way is to subclass and create functionality yourself, or to manky patch the class with a new method.